# Method works on C++ but how to reproduce the same in PHP?

Tags: php, c++, hashcode

I have the following code on c++

```
std::string Battlenet::AccountMgr::CalculateShaPassHash(std::string const& name, std::string const& password)
{
    SHA256Hash email;
    email.UpdateData(name);
    email.Finalize();

    SHA256Hash sha;
    sha.UpdateData(ByteArrayToHexStr(email.GetDigest(), email.GetLength()));
    sha.UpdateData(":");
    sha.UpdateData(password);
    sha.Finalize();

    return ByteArrayToHexStr(sha.GetDigest(), sha.GetLength(), true);
}

std::string ByteArrayToHexStr(uint8 const* bytes, uint32 arrayLen, bool reverse /* = false */)
{
    int32 init = 0;
    int32 end = arrayLen;
    int8 op = 1;

    if (reverse)
    {
        init = arrayLen - 1;
        end = -1;
        op = -1;
    }

    std::ostringstream ss;
    for (int32 i = init; i != end; i += op)
    {
        char buffer[4];
        sprintf(buffer, "%02X", bytes[i]);
        ss << buffer;
    }

    return ss.str();
}
```

I'm trying to reproduce the same result on PHP, and what i did so far:

```
public function RegisterBattleNetAccount($email, $password)
{
      $GLOBALS['mysqli']->query("use {$GLOBALS['db_auth']}");
      //strtoupper
      $pass = hash('sha256', strrev(strtoupper(hash('sha256', $email))).':'.$password);
      $pass = strtoupper(strrev($pass));
      $email = strtoupper($email);
      $stmt = $GLOBALS['mysqli']->prepare("INSERT INTO battlenet_accounts (`email`,`sha_pass_hash`) VALUES (?, ?)");

      $stmt->bind_param("ss", $email, $pass);
      $stmt->execute();       
}
```

Results:

```
C++: 09FEBAB417CF2FA563AC89963519CCAC53D5F556F8BF20D7EEB818A0584A514E
PHP: 4e514a58a018b8eed720bff856f5d553accc19359689ac63a52fcf17b4bafe09
```

what i can do to obtain the same result as C++?

Comment: C'mon, that is not even a valid C++ program.

Comment: An example of your `$email` input would be nice.

Comment: for example mail@mail.com

Comment: And `$password`? Come on mate... Think about it; how am I supposed to be able to reproduce your outputs without your inputs?

Comment: password can be a simple password like "secretpassword"

Comment: Mm, nope: `hash('sha256', strtoupper(hash('sha256', 'mail@mail.com')).':'.'secretpassword')` [does not have the hash in the question](http://codepad.org/qWOA56xe). You're wasting my time -.- Why can't you just tell me what your inputs are?

Comment: i'm giving you my inputs!! lol

Comment: i'm trying to obtain the same result as C++ has seems that the result should be reversed as other user suggested, i tried to reverse the string still with no success

Comment: That "other user" was me. And no you haven't given me your inputs as I have demonstrated with a live example.

Comment: this is my function in php 

http://pastebin.com/11D4kMUq

and as you can see i already tried to reverse it

Comment: this is the function in c++
http://pastebin.com/Z2sRFN9P

and of course the function ByteArrayToHexStr is in the main post

Comment: @SilverSkin Code goes into the main post. And if you actually paid attention to what people are telling you, this would be most beneficial to you. You basically nailed it yourself **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27672672/method-works-on-c-but-how-to-reproduce-the-same-in-php#comment43760323_27672702)**

Comment: @sehe i know but turns out it didnt work

Comment: @SilverSkin it did. You just need to find out how to reverse the string. You can _see_ that the string is basically correct but reversed, right. Good luck

Comment: i did reverse the string , check my code :
$pass = strtoupper(strrev($pass));

Comment: @SilverSkin: It's plainly obvious that a character-by-character reversal is not going to work, as it is _pairs_ of characters that are mirrored in your output. Who actually wrote that C++ code?

Comment: i did it myself, i understood the logic :) thanks anyway, i'm still marking your answer as right :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look closely, you'll see that (case notwithstanding) the two results are the same except that each hex couple is written in reverse order.

**Your C++ version is called with `reverse` as `true`; so, simply don't do that!**

(Then make the casing consistent between the two programs.)

Comment: how can i reverse it in php?